# Multithreading and "just leaking" warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I'm creating a new thread like this:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(myMethod:) 
toTarget:self withObject:filePath];
```

and in the method I do:

```
- (void) myMethod:(NSString*)path{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool alloc];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage) writeToFile:[path stringByAppendingString:@".png"] atomically:NO];
[pool release];
}
```

but keep getting these warnings:

```
*** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x194b1c0 of class NSConcreteMutableData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x309084ff 0x3a0d 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x9100cfbd 0x9100ce42)

*** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x19014c0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
Stack: (0x305a2e6f 0x30504682 0x3a30 0x3050a79d 0x3050a338 0x9100cfbd 0x9100ce42)
```

Isn't creating an NSAutoreleaseNoPool object inside the called method and then releasing it the proper way to use a threaded @selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't fully initialize the autorelease pool:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

// do stuff

[pool drain];
```

Hope this helps